# Protected Excel Macro Enabled Workbook Not saving Plain Non-Macro copy

Tags: excel, vba

This is a protected workbook exposing only the fields that a user should make entries into.  All of this following routine works except the archiving of data from the protected page.  Here's the summary of what it does.

1. Users enter values in a worksheet for 1 week and can save it on a regular basis. This is a macro-enabled workbook.
2. On Monday an 'Admin' user based on Environ$("username") can click a button that clears all of the entries, and saves a plain Excel workbook without any VBA or buttons.
3. The programmatic steps all function and it saves a stripped down version of the page, but there's no data in it.

I have placed an ActiveWorkBook.Save command above the rest of the routine, and it's missing something that I haven't seen yet.

Here's the all of the code related to the Button 2 attached to the Macro "ResetTracker"

```
Sub ResetTracker()

'First save this workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

MsgBox "Please select the location for this file"
Dim strPath As String

Sheets("Setup").Range("A2") = ""

strPath = ""

strPath = GetFolderPath

If strPath <> "" Then
    Debug.Print strPath
   
      
    Sheets("Setup").Range("A2") = strPath

    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to reset and archive the tracker?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
        Range("F8:J10,F13:J15,F18:J20,F23:J25,F28:J30").Select
        Range("F28").Activate
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("F8").Select
    End If

    Dim NewWb As Workbook
    Set NewWb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Requisition Tracker").Copy Before:=NewWb.Sheets(1)

    Dim btn As Shape
    For Each btn In NewWb.Sheets("Weekly Requisition Tracker").Shapes
        btn.Delete
    Next btn


Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'suppress warning message
    Dim i As Long
    With NewWb
        For i = .Sheets.Count To 2 Step -1
            .Sheets(i).Delete
        Next i
        .SaveAs Filename:=strPath & "\Weekly Requisition Tracker_" & DateString & ".xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    MsgBox "Your tracker was successfully saved to: " & strPath
End If


End Sub
```

Public Function GetFolderPath(Optional strTitle As String)

```
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strPath As String
    
    strFile = pickFolderPath(, strTitle)
    If strFile <> "" Then
        'strPath = PathOnly(strFile)
        GetFolderPath = strFile
    End If


End Function

Public Function pickFolderPath(Optional ByVal initPath As String = "", Optional strTitle As String) As String
'Allows user to select a single file from a dialog box (no file type filter)
 Dim FD As Object
 Set FD = Application.FileDialog(4) 'msoFileDialogFolderPicker=4
 FD.InitialFileName = initPath
 
 If strTitle <> "" Then
    FD.Title = strTitle
 End If
 
 FD.AllowMultiSelect = False
 Dim vrtSelectedItem As String
 If FD.Show = -1 Then pickFolderPath = FD.SelectedItems(1)
 Set FD = Nothing
End Function

Public Function DateString() As String
Dim YY As String
Dim MM As String
Dim DD As String
Dim HH As String
Dim nn As String

YY = Year(Now())
MM = Month(Now())
DD = Format(Day(Now()), "00")
HH = Format(Hour(Now()), "00")
nn = Format(Minute(Now()), "00")


DateString = YY & MM & DD & "_" & HH & nn

End Function
```

Comment: Pelease, press a break poin of the line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Requisition Tracker").Copy` and see if the sheet in discussion contains data as you think it should. Then, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Requisition Tracker").Copy` without being followed by `Before:=NewWb.Sheets(1)`, **creates a new workbook with a single sheet having the content of the respective sheet**. Then use `Set NewWb = ActiveWorkbook`. Your existing (following) code should work as you need, I think.

Comment: Yes.  I struggled with that originally, but thanks for the tip about the break point to check if there is data.  Here's what happens:   
1. I put the recommended BreakPoint in 
2. There is no data on that sheet that was copied.
3. I receive run-time error '9': Subscript out of range on:  For Each btn in NewWb.Sheets...
3.  This is why I put the 'Before:=NewWb'  
4. But at least I know that I'm losing my data anyway.   
5. It also doesn't work if I take the protection off. 
Any reason why none of it gets saved?

Comment: What do you mean by "none of it"? I can see that you only copied a sheet and try saving only that sheet plus the former first sheet (according to the default number of sheets **in a new workbook**). But a simpler/faster way should not involve copying the respective sheet in a newly created workbook. As I said above `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly Requisition Tracker").Copy` **does create a new workbook with a single sheet, the copied one**. But not being followed by anything. And, of course, you should not previously create and set any new workbook. Only set it as I suggested above...

Comment: Correct.  It does create one and I removed all the references to the new workbook.  But when I run that line, the new page has no numbers on it.  So, what the heck, I save it and still nothing in the final file.

Comment: This only means that there is nothing on it before creating the new workbook. Try running the code line by line, pressing F8 and see whewe your code clears the respective sheet content.

Comment: I found it.   I needed to move the line you recommended right after the question "Are you sure you want to reset and archive the tracker?"  because, it was always clearing it, before it even copied it to the new workbook.  Can you please post that so I can give you credit?

Comment: I do not think that is necessary to place an answer... I only made some suggestions to help you debugging the code. Based on the fact that your way of using `SaveAs` looked correct. I couldn't even understand that the sheet to be copied was the active one, where you cleared some ranges. Place it in a variable! The answer would be too general to also help somebody else searching for a similar issue. Yor question title does not fit too much the real code problem. Then, some small optimization to directly create the workbook and avoid deleting sheets after that is minor... Glad I could help!